# Proof Check: $ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x-\sin x}{x^2} $

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

The limit can be rewritten as

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x-\sin x}{x^2} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{x} \left[ 1- \frac{\sin x}{x} \right] $$

Recall the inequality,

$$ \cos x < \frac{\sin x}{x} < 1$$

holds for $ x\in (-\pi/2, \pi/2) $.

This provides the new inequalities

$$ 0 < \frac{1}{x} \left[ 1- \frac{\sin x}{x} \right] < \frac{1-\cos x}{x},  \text{ with } x>0 $$

$$ \frac{1-\cos x}{x} < \frac{1}{x} \left[1- \frac{\sin x}{x} \right]< 0,  \text{ with } x<0 $$

Applying the Squeeze Theorem, we get

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{\pm}}  \frac{1}{x} \left[ 1- \frac{\sin x}{x} \right] = 0$$

Note:

$ \lim_{ x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1-\cos x}{x} = 0 $

Comment: Feel free to let me know if I need to add clarity or corrections. Thank you!

Comment: Seems fine as long as the inequality you recalled is allowed to be used.

Comment: Indeed. I'm writing the proof from the point of view of a student briefly introduced to the proof of basic trig. limits and of course the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is right. But I would have used Taylor developments :

$$\frac{x-\sin x}{x^2} \underset{x\rightarrow 0}{=} \frac{x-(x-x^3/6+o(x^3))}{x^2}\underset{x\rightarrow 0}{=}\frac{x}{6}+o(x)\underset{x\rightarrow 0}{\longrightarrow} 0$$

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm unfamiliar with Taylor developments, so onward to explore!

Comment: He has used the tag 'limits-without-l'hopital'. I guess, by extension, Taylor series are not allowed as well

Answer (score 0):

It is a fine and nice argument with trig functions.

Another way to proceed is to use *asymptitics* (see them as Taylor expansions at $x=0$.

Then you can write $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{-(\sin(x) -x)}{x^2} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} -(\frac{-x^3/3!}{x^2} )= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x/6 = 0$$

Comment: I don't think Taylor series are a good idea for a question with the tag "without-l'hopital"

Comment: You are right, but asymptotic equivalences are so important and useful that you can consider my answer as an "encouragement to the reader" to study them. Moreover, what she needs is just the basics and, in some books, what we consider the taylor expansion of functions like sine, cosine, $e^x$ is just the definition of them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to proceed it you don't wanna use L'Hopital, or series expansions.

Let $ x\in\mathbb{R}^{*} $, observe that : $$ \fbox{$\begin{array}{rcl}\displaystyle\frac{x-\sin{x}}{x^{2}}=\frac{x}{2}\int_{0}^{1}{\left(1-y\right)^{2}\cos{\left(xy\right)}\,\mathrm{d}y}\end{array}$} $$

Using the fact that $ \left(\forall t\in\mathbb{R}\right),\ \left|\cos{t}\right|\leq 1 $, we have : \begin{aligned} \left|\frac{x-\sin{x}}{x^{2}}\right|=\frac{\left|x\right|}{2}\left|\int_{0}^{1}{\left(1-y\right)^{2}\cos{\left(xy\right)}\,\mathrm{d}y}\right|&\leq\frac{\left|x\right|}{2}\int_{0}^{1}{\left(1-y\right)^{2}\left|\cos{\left(xy\right)}\right|\mathrm{d}y}\\&\leq\frac{\left|x\right|}{2}\int_{0}^{1}{\left(1-y\right)^{2}\,\mathrm{d}y}=\frac{\left|x\right|}{6}\underset{x\to 0}{\longrightarrow}0 \end{aligned}

Thus : $$ \lim\limits_{x\to 0}{\frac{x-\sin{x}}{x^{2}}}=0 $$